# Find index of min element in matlab

Tags: matlab

Here I have two matrix, one indicating cost and the other determines when to take into comparison.

```
cost =      [0.2 0.0 0.3; 0.4 0 0; 0.5 0 0];
available = [1   1   0  ; 1   0 0; 0   0 0];
available = logical(available);
```

I want to get the index of the min available element in the cost matrix, which in this case would compare `0.2`, `0.0` and `0.4` and return the index of `0.0`, which is `(1, 2)` or `4` in the cost matrix.

I tried

```
mul = cost .* available;     % Zero if not available, but I can't know if it is zero because cost is zero
mul(~mul) = nan;             % Set zero to be NaN
[minVal, minId] = min(mul)
```

This will help to get the min non-zero cost but if there exists zero elements which are available, it would be wrong.

So is there a better way to do so?

Comment: Off-topic: you should refrain from naming variables like functions (for instance `min`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions. Both essentially involve converting all non-available costs to `Inf`.

```
%#Set up an example
Cost =      [0.2 0 0.3; 0.4 0 0; 0.5 0 0];
Available = [1   1   0; 1   0 0; 0   0 0];

%#Transform non-available costs to Inf
Cost(Available == 0) = Inf;

%#Obtain indices using find
[r, c] = find(Cost == min(min(Cost)))

%#Obtain linear indices and convert using ind2sub
[~, I1] = min(Cost(:));
[r2, c2] = ind2sub(size(Cost), I1);
```

Both solutions will only return the first minimum value in the instance that there is not a unique minimum. Also, the method will fail in the perverse case that all the available costs are `Inf` (but I guess you've got bigger problems if all your costs are infinite...).

I've done a few speed tests, and the second method is definitely faster, no matter what the dimensions of `Cost`, so should be strictly preferred. Also, if you only want linear indices and not subscript indices then you can of course drop the call to `ind2sub`. However, this doesn't give you huge savings in efficiency, so if there is a preference for subscript indices then you should use them.

Comment: I suppose this is not quit right. `min(cost(available));` returns the minId in a new matrix returned by `cost(available)`, which in this case is 3. But I want the id in cost matrix, which should be 4.

Comment: Index of the first min element is enough.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I think using find to get the id is not very efficient. I'll use `[min, minId]=min(Cost(:))` instead.

Comment: @Ovilia That will only get you the linear index, not the subscript index. You'll need a call to sub2ind in there also if you want the subscripts. I'm also doing a few speed tests and will update my answer soon.